# Does the IReadOnlySessionState resets timeouts if slidingExpiration is enabled?

Tags: session, session-state, readonly

It is know that when you enable the slidingExpiration (`slidingExpiration="true"`) the autheticate timeout will be reset with every request. But what I'm not sure, and I was not able to find when this actually happen. Whether it happen when the request Get the resource or on Release time. If the second is true the slidingExpiration only will reset the timeout if we are implementing IRequiresSessionState because is the only interface that acquires exclusive lock, therefore the only which need a release item (SetAndReleaseItemExclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution using both interfaces and watching the results... **With slidingExpiration enabled the tiemeout is being reset regardless you're using IReadOnlySessionState or IRequiresSessionState**

Below the scenario where I tried on.

I have an application which has some classic ASP screens living together with .Net pages. To avoid timeouts if the user is only using the classic ASP pages I have a generic handler called KeepAlive (KeepAlive.ashx) which  is being called every time a Classic asp page is open. The code of the ashx is pretty simple

```
public class KeepAlive : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

I changed the `<sessionState timeout="1" />` in the web.config so I don't need to wait for 20 minutes :P and I changed the KeepAlive to use IReadOnlySessionState. If I keep on opening the classic ASP screens within the time frame of 1 minute I don't get Authentication timeouts this means that the timeouts are being reset regardless were're using exclusive locks or not.

Hope this helps someone else  :)